# How to know if images from a game window are matching with my images bank? ( Python )

Tags: python, image, matching, detect, riot-games-api

In the game there are some "characters icons". They are always at the same position on the window, but I need my program to check all of them and return me information about them. So it needs to check every positions, and tell me for all of them who's this character in it.
But everytime I try to find how to do it, I only get deeplearning results from object detection...

An easier way is possible right ?

Or I still need to use openCV or things like this ?

Thx <3

Image example if needed : https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/391121201772363779/1025045209203101747/unknown.png

Answer (score 0):

This is the "easier" way:
League of Legends has a "Client"-Api you can use to obtain the ARAM bench. It is called LCU and is not officially documented.

Here is an example for python, you need to be in champ select:

```py
from lcu_driver import Connector

connector = Connector()

#Connected to League Client
@connector.ready
async def connect(connection):
    lobby = await connection.request('GET', '/lol-champ-select/v1/session')
    lobby = await summoner.json()
    print(lobby)

connector.start()
```

If you have any further question, I would recommend you to join the Riot Games Third-Party-Developer Discord, there are many people who can help you  regarding League API questions.